# Create a 3d surface plot from a list of dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, scipy

I have a parametric model when solved produces multiple .csv files when a certain parameter is varied. E.g. variation of kinetic energy vs time with variation in thickness or any other parameter. I want to generate a 3d surface plot which can show the variation of energy vs time with parameter variation.

I have created a list of dataframes (each dataframe corresponds to a specific .csv file) and, I would like to know how to proceed from here. Please let me know if there is a better way of compiling the data without losing uniqueness.

[image: sample Energy vs time plot]

[image: List of dataframes]

```
DataFrame
(4, 2)
    Time    Kinetic_Energy
0   0.2799346745    0.0
1   0.55984050035   210.14064026
2   0.83978486061   249.58207703
3   1.0001842976000002  266.83724976
```

```
DataFrame
(4, 2)
    Time    Kinetic_Energy
0   0.2799346745    0.0
1   0.55990374088   1220.291748
2   0.8399130702    1306.4038085999998
3   1.0000931025    1012.7531127999998
```

Each dataframe contains an energy vs time plot for a certain parameter.

```
DataFrame
(4, 2)
    Time    Kinetic_Energy
0   0.2799346745    0.0
1   0.5598949194    1513.1392822
2   0.83991670609   1294.0274658
3   1.0002003908    1356.4621582
```

```
DataFrame
(4, 2)
    Time    Kinetic_Energy
0   0.2799346745    0.0
1   0.5599192977    1.6380735636000001
2   0.8399435281800001  5.835875988
3   1.0001727343    7.5012774467
```

Comment: I hope your CSV file contains the value of your parameter. Them you can take that value from the file name, put it into a column called parameter and concatenate all the dataframes together row wise. This way you have your 2d independent variables in two rows parameter and time, and your dependent variable k.e. in another column. That's then the input for your surface plot.

Comment: I have my parameters stored in a separate list. I will try to do as you suggested and update you. Thank you for your help.